# wp_redirect Redirecting to previous page after login?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to go previous page by using `wp_redirect`.

I am using wp_redirect like in below code.

```
<?php

global $current_user;
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
        wp_redirect("http://adb.web.com/");
}

$args = array(  
    //'redirect' => home_url(),
    'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ),
    'id_username' => 'user',
    'id_password' => 'pass',
   );


wp_login_form( $args );

?>
```

What I need to write code instead off `wp_redirect("http://adb.web.com/");`

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: whats happening on my question, can anyone please explain who gives down vote ??

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`wp_login_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) to link to your login page (you should be), you don't need to do anything special:

```
// I use get_permalink() to get the current URL
<a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">Login</a>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `wp_redirect()` at all. Please read the link I posted. WordPress already handles redirects to the previous page, if you use `wp_login_url()`

Comment: sir I have made a wordpress template for login page so obviously I will give the link of my that page template not to href URL as you give.